# Property 'push' is missing in type '(request: NtlmRequest, response: Response) => void'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings

I want to simply extend the `Request`object from the Express framework with a custom property:

```
import express = require('express')

export interface NtlmRequest extends express.Request {
     ntlm: NtlmInfo
}
```

Which is used as argument-type for the `express.Request` instead.

```
let app = express();
app.all('*', (request:NtlmRequest, response:Response) => {
    console.log(request.ntlm.UserName)
});

app.listen(1243)
```

`NtlmInfo` is another interface which simply contains string propertys like this:

```
export interface NtlmInfo { UserName: string  [...] }
```

But this gave me a error that the request Type is not compatible:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(request: NtlmRequest, response: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
  Type '(request: NtlmRequest, response: Response) => void' is not assignable to type '(RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[]'.
    Property 'push' is missing in type '(request: NtlmRequest, response: Response) => void'.
```

Couldn't understand this since I inherit from the original `express.Request` object and looked in the Typing definitions which doesn't have any `push` attribute present.

Following packages are installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-ntlm": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.7",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first one is easy to fix, for `response` i believe you are using the `lib.d.ts` version of `Response`. You should use `express.Response`

The second is a bit more subtle. To use `NtlmRequest` as the request type, you will need to make `ntlm` optional. The compiler, expects `all` will take a function which has the first parameter `express.Request`, so the function you pass can't require that the first parameter will have more properties than `express.Request`

```
export interface NtlmRequest extends express.Request {
     ntlm?: NtlmInfo
}
//Will work
app.all('*', (request:NtlmRequest, response:express.Response) => {
    console.log(request.ntlm.UserName)
});
```

Another option is to extends the global express `Request`. This will add the `ntlm` property to **all** request instance:

```
import * as express from 'express'
interface NtlmInfo { UserName: string}
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            ntlm: NtlmInfo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The version of `Response` was correct, since I already used `express.Response` like in the example code. But the second one was my issue: Changing the `ntlm` property to optional fixed the problem. Thanks! :)